# Rails carousel producing 'undefined method `image_path' in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a carousel in a Rails app and can't seem to get around a problem I'm having. I'm new to Rails - so it's probably a simple resolution. This produces a 'undefined method `image_path' in my controller. Thanks in advance for any help!

Here is my controller:

```
def golf
    images = ['CreekCoverLarge.jpg', 'CreekWindmillLarge.jpg', 'CreekExtraLarge.jpg', 'CreekExtra2Large.jpg']
    @paths = images.map {|name| image_path name}
end
```

And this is my view:

```
<div class="item active">
   <%= @paths.each do |path| %>
      <%= link_to(image_tag(path, class: "img-responsive", size: "600x440"), "#", data: {toggle: "modal", target: "#myModal"}, "onclick"=>"getImage(this)", "data-img-address" => path) %>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

`ActionController::Base.helpers.image_path`

Although, cant you just loop through `images` in the view and call `image_path` there?

**Edit:**

Example as requested:

Controller:

```
def golf
    @images = ['CreekCoverLarge.jpg', 'CreekWindmillLarge.jpg', 'CreekExtraLarge.jpg', 'CreekExtra2Large.jpg']
end
```

View:

```
<div class="item active">
   <%= @images.each do |path| %>
      <%= link_to(image_path(path, class: "img-responsive", size: "600x440"), "#", data: {toggle: "modal", target: "#myModal"}, "onclick"=>"getImage(this)", "data-img-address" => path) %>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

**This is untested, but should work.**

Comment: Can you give me an example of how I might structure the loop in the views page?

Comment: Thanks @DickieBoy I had to do a little tweaking of it, but it definitely set me on the right path!